# Crystal reports viewer got error the ) is missing , error in formula record selection

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I'm using CRforVS_13_0_16 in MS Visual Studio 2012 to make a report. Here's the code :

```
 Private Sub formCRisiulang_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call openconn()
    Dim no = FrmIsiUlang.Fakturtxt.Text
    CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "(ViewIsiUlang.Faktur_Penjualan) Like'" & no & "'"
   CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```

but then it show this error

[errorreport_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNUUV.png)

is there any mistakes in my codes?

Comment: have you promt your params? image shows bracket is missing

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't get your point. I'm very new at this. What kind of parameters? can you show me an example? thanks before

Answer (score -1):

Your code :
CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "(ViewIsiUlang.Faktur_Penjualan) Like'" & no & "'"

try to use `{ViewIsiUlang.Faktur_Penjualan}
"{}" not "()"`

Other example :

```
Form5.CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{tb_supply.supply_id} = '" + Txtsupplyid.Text + "'"
```